# User/Password Verification using ASP.NET against a MySQL database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, validation

**strong text**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["moverschoiceConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select Email, Password from brokercenter where Email = '" + txtLoginEmail.Text + "'";
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            if (reader["Password"].ToString() == txtLoginPassword.Text)
            {
                reader.Close();
                Response.Redirect("BrokerResources.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblLoginError.Text = "Invalid Password";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblLoginError.Text = "Invalid Email Address";
        }

    }
```

Please understand that I just got done learning entry level C# and was hired by this company to develop sites.  The previous .NET guy just left so I do not know what he was doing where.  This is my first question on this site so I aplogize if it is not formatted correctly.  I am new to this and could use any help.  Simply put, I have two textboxes and a button.  I can get a user to create an account and it goes into the dB but I cannot get the email (username) and password to be verified.  When I click the button, nothing happens.  This company has numerous sites so I tried to just copy and paste from another login button and change what I need to match this current sites info, but nothing.  I checked around for about two days and tried many versions of login code but still nothing.  I do not know what is already installed on this system.  Again, I am entry level (literally just completed the course on the 10th), so use small words.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should always close reader, try google how to use using in .net

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it looks like your code will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (I don't see any escaping, nor use of parameterized queries). You should also store a salted & hashed version of the password, **NEVER** the raw password itself! It's generally also a good idea to not give different error messages for password/username being invalid: different messages will allow an attacker to sniff out what usernames are valid!

Comment: Thanks guys!  In regards to closing the reader, I have it closing before redirecting, is that in the wrong place?

Comment: @user1223835 it's better to declare the reader within a using block, so you are sure that it will be close. An open reader prevents you from doing more queries on the same connection

Answer (score 1):

After click on the button `btnLogin_Click()` should fire.
After `btnLogin_Click` you should have a redirection to another page   `Response.Redirect` or a feedback to user  `lblLoginError.Text =` .

If nothing happens, I suppose that  `btnLogin_Click()` is not linked to the button: on aspx page you should have `<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server"  onclick="btnLogin_Click"   ..>`

Anyway, put a breakpoint anywhere inside `btnLogin_Click()`, start debugging and looks if it fires!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it may solve your problem

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["moverschoiceConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
  conn.Open();
  OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  cmd.CommandText = "select Email, Password from brokercenter where Email = '" + txtLoginEmail.Text + "'";
  OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  While(reader.Read())
  {
    if (reader["Password"].ToString() == txtLoginPassword.Text)
    {
        reader.Close();
        Response.Redirect("BrokerResources.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblLoginError.Text = "Invalid Password";
    }
  }
  lblLoginError.Text = "Invalid Email Address"; 
  reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am better understanding this process with that code!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new, I want to help you learn a few things about this code. I'm going to outline what the code is doing:

- The connection string which is used to tell the application how to connect and authenticate to the database is being fetched from a APS.net built in configuration entry
- The connection to the sql database is being initialized and opened
- Problem 1 - connection is being opened but upon any failure, connection is not closed, wrap the connection in a using block to safeguard
- A Command is being constructed to query the SQL server
- Problem 2 - connection string is not using binded parameters, which means it is open to SQL injection attack, very common mistake several years ago
- Command is being executed to fetch a rowset that meets the criteria of the query
- Query is looking for rows that match where email is equal to what was entered in the textbox for the email address
- Check the reader for any results, if none, return error about email
- Problem 3 - the connection wasn't closed here which will lead to issues later, see problem 1
- Since we have a row, check the rows password value to compare with what was entered
- Problem 4 - the connection isnt closed on error again, see problem 1
- Problem 5 - password is in plain text and should be secured
- If password matched, redirect to new page
- Potential Problem 6 - since nothing is done to mark the user logged in, you might be able to skip the login page which is a breach in security

Also, as someone mentioned already, check the Asp.net script for the button click event, the method name needs to match what is specified on the page itself to wire up.

Hopefully this gives you something to work on and hopefully it will guide you in your learnings.

All the best

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate all those notes!  I was able to identify some more issues with your notes and the code above.

Comment: Welcome! Hopefully this gets you on the path you need. When you feel more comfortable, look at a Membership Provider as well as forms based authentication to replace this stuff. It's built into Asp.Net and is loads safer/secure/easier than rolling your own.

Comment: I agree! Using the WSAT and forms based authentication is how we learned in class, and how I would prefer to do it, but this is something I inherited from the previous guy. If I could I would redo the whole thing. Truth be told I am only entry level but this position is easily mid or higher. I am the only .NET person here and way over my head and not happy about it at all! I plan on using StackOverflow most of the day. Thank you for your help!